# Proving equation (calculus)

Tags: calculus

I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction for solving this. I just can't get it. Thanks

Prove $ ({x+1})^{1/3} < 1 + {\frac13}x $ for x > 0

Answer (score 1):

y = (x+1)^1/3 
y >= 1;

Your equation is y<(y^3 + 2)/3

<=> y^3-3y+2 >=0  <=> (y-1)(y^2+y-2) >=0  <=> (y-1)(y-1)(y+2) >=0

qed

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation $h(x)=1+\dfrac{1}{3}x-(1+x)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$

$h^{'}(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}[1-\dfrac{1}{{1+x}^{\frac{2}{3}}}]$

Since $x>0\implies \dfrac{1}{{1+x}^{\frac{2}{3}}}<1$

Hence $h^{'}(x)>0\forall x>0$

So $h$ is increasing so $h(x)>h(0)\implies 1+\dfrac{1}{3}x>(1+x)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$